# MDF file in App_Data, is it thread safe?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, mdf

I have a local database file (`.mdf`) in my `app_data` directory of my C# asp.net mvc program.

If I have many user on my site all reading data from the `.mdf` file is it thread safe? This would be read only, and updated a few times a week.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `.mdf` is being handled by **SQL Server Express** which is installed on your machine (or any other machine that uses your application), and SQL Server **is** thread-safe in that you can throw any number of concurrent requests at it and it won't break under that kind of workload.

Comment: so, an MDF file must have SQL Server Express install to work. It can not work stand-alone.

Comment: @Bill: **YES**, there **MUST** be a SQL Server **Express** instance to work with the `.mdf` file

Comment: What about SQL Compact edition, would this work stand alone. I don't see it in Visual Studio 2013

Comment: @Bill: SQL Server Compact is being deprecated in favor of SQL Server **Express** (and the `LocalDB` version thereof in SQL Server 2012)